# Excel formula is correct but shows #VALUE error

Tags: excel, formula

I have a rather simple formula in multiple cells which works fine in all but the first cell, which evaluates to #VALUE. I've stripped down the formula to a minimum. The reference cells are Time formatted, though are initially blank. The basic formula in cell I2 is:

```
=IF(G2="","")
```

This stripped down formula evaluates to FALSE. The full formula evaluates to #VALUE
I3, I4 and so forth have the same 'G3, G4' format
Cells G2 and G3 and so forth are blank but Time formatted

The confusing part though, is if I copy/ paste the formula from elsewhere to I2, the error resolves. Dragging the formula doesn't work. Visually, I can't see any differences. What am I missing?

Comment: what is the rest of the formula?  Most likely the rest cannot deal with the `FALSE` return.

Comment: I've also just noticed that Control C (to copy) doesn't resolve the issue but actually highlighting the formula in the formula bar and copying via mouse drop down does.

Comment: This basic formula isn't working correctly, so the full formula is irrelevant

Comment: it is working correctly, you do not have anything in the false part of the IF so if it is not blank the formula will return `FALSE` and if the rest of the formula is such that `FALSE` is not a viable return it will error.  So either you are missing something in the formula you are showing or we need to see more, as is there is no way to answer this.  It is doing what it is designed to do.  If the cell is not blank it will return `FALSE`, unless you tell it what to do when false, that is the design and is the correct output.

Comment: I did say that G2 is blank but formatted for time. The formula is correct for referencing blank cells

Comment: Then look at the data in G2 and make sure it is not a space or other non-printable characters in the cell.  Is G2 filled by a formula?

Comment: Sigh... It had a hidden space. Thanks

Comment: NP, sorry about going down the wrong tract.  Glad to help find it.

Comment: you can use `=IF(trim(G2)="","")` instead. ( :